# Create an instance of an object inside a method

Tags: php

I read a book on OOP PHP, can not understand what the author means:

```
class Registry {
    /**
    * Array of objects
    */
    private $objects;

   public function createAndStoreObject($object, $key) {
       require_once($object.'.class.php');
       $this->objects[$key] = new $object($this);
   }
}
```

1) $this->objects[$key] - We saving a private class array value.
2) new $object($this) - I do not understand where we take the object $object (if this array) and what is meant in the sense of $this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is example of Registry Design Pattern, which creates objects similar as the Factory Design Pattern. In this pattern, a class simply creates the object you want to use without necessarily knowing what kind of object it creates. In your example `createAndStoreObject` function creates a new instance of a class using a variable class name.

If, for example, `$object = 'Foo'`, then is the same as:

```
   require_once('Foo'.'.class.php');
   $this->objects[$key] = new Foo($this);
```

The meaning of `$this` passed to the constructor is that all objects created can have access to the Registry object

Answer (score 2):

```
$class = 'Foo';
$foo   = new $class;
```

is the same as

```
$foo = new Foo;
```

That explains what `new $object` does. And while it's instantiating a new instance of whatever `$object` is, it is passing `$this` to the object's constructor. I.e. it's passing a reference to the `Registry` object to the object that is being constructed.

Answer (score 0):

$this refers to the current object within scope so in your case the Registry class so you could call to the $object variable within the scope of you class by using $this->objects